# Using ModelAndView object properties inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am returning a list from my Controller as list to view and I am passing this list object to my javascript function like this

```
window.onload = function() {
 showDirectory("$(S3DirectoryList)");
};
```

`S3DirectoryList` is the object that is returned from controller.

This is my model class

```
class Directory {
    String folderName;
    HashMap< String, String> objects;
    List<Directory> dChild;
}
```

I want to use the `folderName` property of `Directory` in function.

Currently my javascript function is defined like this

```
function showDirectory( dirList) {
    var markup="";
    <c:forEach var="dir" items="dirList">
        markup += ${dir.folderName} + "<br>";
    </c:forEach>
    document.getElementById("dispdir").innerHTML = markup;
}
```

Comment: you cannot use a javascript parameter(dirList) as parameter to c:forEach. c:forEach runs at server side and will have finished running when your javascript function(showDirectory) is called at client side.

Comment: So, instead of c:forEach what should I use, dirList contains the whole information of directory which I want to show in a view

Comment: see my answer; I added the function showDirectory; don't forget the double quotes around "$(S3DirectoryList)"

Comment: sorry, forget the double qoutes; those are needed when $(S3DirectoryList) returns a string, but it's an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some code to your Directory class. If you run it(I also added a Main method for testing purposes), you see it creates a list of directories and serializes this list as JSON. I added a constructor to make it easy to create some directories. I also added a getJSON method that serializes a directory. I added a getJSON(List directories) method to serialize a list of directories.

If you see to it this serialized list gets into your variable S3DirectoryList you can pass it to your javascript function as follows:

```
function showDirectory(dirList) {
    var markup = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < dirList.length; i++) {
        markup += dirList[i].folderName + "<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById("dispdir").innerHTML = markup;
}

window.onload = function() {
    showDirectory($(S3DirectoryList));
};
```

the Directory class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Directory{

    String folderName;
    HashMap<String, String> objects;
    List<Directory> dChild;

    public Directory(String folderName, String[] objects) {
        this.folderName = folderName;
        this.objects = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i = i + 2) {
            this.objects.put(objects[i], objects[i + 1]);
        }
        this.dChild = new ArrayList<Directory>();
    }

    public void addChildDirectory(Directory childDirectory) {
        if(this.dChild == null)
            this.dChild = new ArrayList<Directory>();
        this.dChild.add(childDirectory);
    }

    public String toJSON() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append("{");
        b.append("'folderName': '").append(folderName  == null ? "" : folderName).append("'");
        b.append(",objects: {");
        if(objects != null) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> objectsIterator = objects.entrySet().iterator();
            if(objectsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> object = objectsIterator.next();
                b.append("'").append(object.getKey()).append("': '").append(object.getValue()).append("'");
            }
            while (objectsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> object = objectsIterator.next();
                b.append(",'").append(object.getKey()).append("': '").append(object.getValue()).append("'");
            }
        }
        b.append("}");
        b.append(",'dChild': ");
        b.append("[");
        if(dChild != null) {
            if(dChild.size() > 0)
                b.append(dChild.get(0).toJSON());
            for(int i = 1; i < dChild.size(); i++) {
                b.append(",").append(dChild.get(i).toJSON());
            }
        }
        b.append("]");
        b.append("}");
        return b.toString();
    }

    public static String getJSON(List<Directory> directories) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append("[");
        if(directories.size() > 0)
            b.append(directories.get(0).toJSON());
        for(int i = 1; i < directories.size(); i++) {
            b.append(",").append(directories.get(i).toJSON());
        }
        b.append("]");
        return b.toString();
    }

    private static Directory generateDirectory(int seed) {
        List<Directory> directories = new ArrayList<Directory>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            directories.add(
                    new Directory(
                            "folderName_" + seed + "_" + i, 
                            new String[]{"k_" + seed + "_" + i + "_1", "v_" + seed + "_" + i + "_1", "k_" + seed + "_" + i + "_2", "k_" + seed + "_" + i + "_2"}));
        }
        Directory directory_root = directories.get(0);
        Directory directory_1_0 = directories.get(1);
        Directory directory_1_1 = directories.get(2);
        Directory directory_1_0_0 = directories.get(3);
        Directory directory_1_0_1 = directories.get(4);
        directory_root.addChildDirectory(directory_1_0);
        directory_root.addChildDirectory(directory_1_1);
        directory_1_0.addChildDirectory(directory_1_0_0);
        directory_1_0.addChildDirectory(directory_1_0_1);
        return directory_root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Directory> directories = new ArrayList<Directory>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            directories.add(generateDirectory(i));
        }
        System.out.println(toJSON(directories));
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting JSON Output as per your code but I am not getting required output on my WebPage, sorry but I have just started working on JSON

Comment: Do you succeed in putting the directories list serialized as JSon in your model?

Comment: Yes, I have done that and json string is passed to the view successfully.

Comment: No, alert is not getting output

Comment: don't you use some kind of debugger for your browser? firebug maybe. The console output from a debugger might tell you more.

Comment: have you removed the double quotes around $(S3DirectoryList)?

Comment: yes, I have done that, and logs are saying
"Added Model Object 'S3DirectoryList' of type [java.lang,string]"
when Model is returning to view by controller

Comment: those are java logs, not logs from a javascript debugger...if the alert fails, there must be some javascript error. a javascript debugger like firebug, would tell you the error.

Comment: window.onload = function() {
   showDirectory([{folderName: "20140601.csv",objects: [expiredpoints.txt: "20140601.csv/expiredpoints.txt"],childDirs: [{folderName: "20140601-test",objects: [CustomerID.txt: "20140601.csv/20140601-test/CustomerID.txt"],childDirs: []},{folderName: "test-folder",objects: [Amazon_Points_proposal20110421_final.docx: "20140601.csv/test-folder/Amazon_Points_proposal20110421_final.docx"],childDirs: []}]},{folderName: "20140602.csv",objects: [Form 2 Guide.pdf: "20140602.csv/Form 2 Guide.pdf"],childDirs: []}]);
  };

Error: Missing ] after Element List

Comment: maybe the slashes (/) are causing problems...I would first try it with some simple dummy JSON value, just to see if your javascript function works.

Comment: I have resolved the issue and everything is working fine now, thank you. The error was coming because you forgot to append "" in key Names.

Comment: :-), alright, good luck with it further, feel free to mark my answer as the correct one